# Execute undefined while making embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

My code:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'canyouhelp'){

        client.commands.get('newmodreportsupport').execute(message, args, Discord)

    }
});

--in commands folder--

module.exports ={
    name: 'canyouhelp',
    description: "Help around the server in general",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#763782')
        .setTitle('Help around the server!')
        .setURL('https://discord.gg/qVvvGW4')
        .setDescription('This should guide you around the server!')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'New to Discord ‍', value: 'So your new to discord? Well thats no problem! Discord is a very easy platform to use. For a detailed explination on how to use it type "-newtothegame" in chat and I will get back to you'},
            {name: 'Need to Talk to a Moderator ‍♂️', value: 'You need to get in touch with a moderator, admin or helper well then just type "-getmethroughtoamod" and I will get back to you!'}

        )
        .setFooter('Make sure you type in the commands letter for letter or it will not work');

        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }

}
```

The javascript file in commands folder is called newmodreportsupport.js

Terminal: TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

I cant understand why this is happening can someone please explain and hopefully correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

inside `client.commands.get('newmodreportsupport').execute(message, args, Discord)` you need to specify the name of the module which is 'canyouhelp' for you, not the file name. so it should be:

```
client.commands.get('canyouhelp').execute(message, args, Discord)
```

Also we can't see your whole code but I imagine you don't even have the bot.commands collection. You need to load your command modules into that like so:

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);  
}
```

So your code should look like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);  
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is ready!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'canyouhelp'){

        client.commands.get('canyouhelp').execute(message, args, Discord)

    }
});
    
bot.login(token);
```